# deserialization not working

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm attempting to serialize and deserialize an object but it's coming back as null. Why is this?

```
car carToSerialize = new car() {
   engine = ....
};

NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(stream, carToSerialize);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
car deserializedCar = (car)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, instead of just a snippet.

Comment: How about saving serialized data to file/output and seeing what gets saved? Just as a first step of figuring out what's wrong :)

Comment: What does your `car` class look like? (i.e. have you added attributes to support the `DataContractSerializer`?)

Comment: *The serializer can serialize types to which either the DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute attribute has been applied. It also serializes types that implement ISerializable.* - from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx).

Comment: are you sure car is a serializable type?

Comment: I've added [DataContractAttribute] to the car class.

Comment: did you decorate the properties of the car class with DataMember attribute?

Comment: The code you posted is perfectly fine on it's own. Please supply a non-working version.

Comment: can you post the code for the car class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that you can use the NetDataContractSerializer, the car class should have the following

- The car class is decorated by the DataContractAttribute attribute
- The serializable members should be decorated with DataMemberAttribute. It is not necessary to have the member as public.